# What micron level is good for carbon filtering your water?

Tags: water, water-filtration

I went and built a version of [this filtration system](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showthread.php?t=29145), but the only filter I could find at Home Depot was a 5 micron. The guy in that thread seems to be using a .5 micron. I have been using water coming out of a Brita pitcher (which I love the taste of), however it is very cumbersome to do it this way, which is why I wanted to do this. So I have a few questions concerning water filtration on this,

1. Is a 5 micron enough? Is it to much?
2. Why does Brita not tell what micron rating their filters are? Better yet, many of the filter manufactures seem to not tell it.
3. Either way I go, should I drop a campden tablet in for good measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 microns is fine for brewing water. At the micron/sub-micron level you're filtering yeast and flavor compounds. Some people do filter their *beer* at this level for clarity/consistency/packaging concerns, but that's by-and-large not necessary itself. For most municipal water, you're looking just to filter macro compounds, and 5 microns is more than enough, I think.

If you're using an active carbon block, you need to run it below one gallon/minute to have a chance to break down chloramines, which your water supply might use. Chlorine and chloramine will be reduced almost instantly by a small amount (let's say 50µg/gallon to be safe) of Campden. My regular process is carbon-block filtration of my brewing water at a not-particularly-reduced speed, and add potassium meta-bisulfate (Campden) for dealing with chlormaines.

Comment: Okay, so I should try and run the water at a slower speed then I guess to help this out? I currently am hooking this thing up to my sink spout, and it is running super fast out of there if I put it on full power.

Comment: Also, do you have any idea what Brita's micron rating is? I could not find it anywhere, but I was trying to make this be comparable.

Comment: I do not, sorry, I'd just be googling for it.

Comment: Yeah, I already looked everywhere. Its stupid that a bunch of the filter manufacturers do not say to what level they filter. So as far as the speed on the water goes, should I just slow that down?

Answer (score 1):

0.5um is perfectly fine for water filtration.
Keep in mind that the porosity of the filter is only good for removing non-solubilized particles in the water.  Its the activated carbon or other elements that you want for neutralizing things like chlorine or other hazardous contaminants.

Even in the Britta, the pore size isn't whats stripping out the soluble flavor molecules that make the water taste odd.

Comment: Right. So do these whole house filters have the ion exchange that the Brita does?

Comment: Only if they say the do.  I have a carbon filter mounted under my kitchen sick.  It has its own mini faucet.  Its used for just drinking water at the sink.  Its purely a carbon filter.  I know there are other cartridges that say ion exchange on them. So you have to look at them and pick one that does.